# problemas al ejecutar ansible

Tags: ssh

al ejecutar ansible-playbook me sale es de error

```
failed: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
Shared connection to xxx.xx.xx.xxx closed.
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema parece deberse a que no tienes instalado Python en el servidor al que accede ansible (ese xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx que has enmascarado).

También es posible que tengas instalado Python 3.x en el servidor y uses un Ansible inferior a la versión 2.2, que es en la que se añadió el soporte inicial para Python 3.x.

Asegurate de que Python está instalado en el servidor y que es una versión adecuada. Sin indicar qué versión de Ansible usas no puedo decirte cuál es la versión mínima de Python que necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso como ha indicado sanzante lo que parece es que en ese servidor tengas que indicarle el path de python con una variable en el fichero hosts por ejemplo:

```
[Hosts]
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
[Hosts:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

Si de la lista de host a los que apuntas sabes cuales de ellos no usan la version std que busca por defecto ansible que es /usr/bin/python, puedes definir una etiqueta en la lista de hosts para aquellos servidores que solo tengan por ejemplo python3 o que tengan alguna instalacion anomala de python en otra ruta.